# I want Json.NET to fail deserializing a missing or undefined value type

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, deserialization, non-nullable

In the code below, I want both `DeserializeObject` calls to throw an exception.

```
public class MyObj
{
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var jsonString = "{ }";

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObj>(jsonString); // Doesn't throw

    jsonString = "{ \"MyInt\": null }";

    obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObj>(jsonString); // Does throw
}
```

I would have expected there be a setting which does the reverse of `JsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling`, but I've not been able to find it.

For context, I'm using Json.NET as the request deserializer for an Azure Function API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `JsonProperty` attribute with `Required = Required.Always` :

```
public class MyObj
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}
```

From [Required enum](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Required.htm) doc:

> Always    ... The property must be defined in JSON and cannot be a null
> value.